# How to center text within a parent div that has children divs of different sizes (flexbox)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering, text-align

I'm creating a site with Flexbox (which I'm fairly new at using). I want to put the name of the site and the menu dropdown button on the same line. I was able to do this successfully with Flexbox, however the Title isn't centered on the page itself. I'm aware that this is because the menu button has a flex-grow of 1 while the title has a flex-grow of 8. I did this on purpose for spacing, however now the Title isn't centered on the entire page.

I've tried leaving the title div blank and just writing a title outside of the div, but this places the text before the parent container.

```
<body>
    <div class="parent container">
        <!--Navigational Bar-->
        <div class="Nav">
            <div id="Nav_Button">
                <p>Button</p>
            </div>
            <div id="Nav_Title">
                <h3>Super Snack Stadium</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
.parent_container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

/*Containers within ".parent container"*/

.Nav {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    /*Flex Child Code*/
    order:1;
    /*Flex Parent Code*/
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;

}

/*--------Children of .Nav ---------*/

#Nav_Button {
    border: 1px solid black;
    /*Flex Child Code*/
    order: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

#Nav_Title {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    /*Flex Child Code*/
    order: 2;
    flex-grow: 8;
}
```

I want to be able to center the title for the entire page (not just within the container its in) using Flexbox if possible.

Comment: you need to close your `<div class="parent container">` with `</div>`. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:** Set the `Nav` `position:relative;`

```
 .Nav {
   border: 1px solid black;
   text-align: center;
   /*Flex Child Code*/
   order:1;
  /*Flex Parent Code*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position:relative;
}
```

**Step 2:** make `h3` absolute.

```
h3 {
  position:absolute;
}
```

Now, `h3`is taken out of the document flow, but it can be positioned based on the closest `relative` element.

In this case, we have made `.Nav` as `relative`. So, `h3` will use `.Nav` for reference. Since `.Nav` occupies full width of the screen, all we need is to position `h3` to the center of `.Nav` using `left` and `transform`

**Step 3:**

```
h3 {
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}
```

**Final:**

```css
.parent_container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

/*Containers within ".parent container"*/

.Nav {
   border: 1px solid black;
   text-align: center;
   /*Flex Child Code*/
   order:1;
  /*Flex Parent Code*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position:relative;
}
/*--------Children of .Nav ---------*/

#Nav_Button {
    border: 1px solid black;
    /*Flex Child Code*/
    order: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

#Nav_Title {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    /*Flex Child Code*/
    order: 2;
    flex-grow: 8;
}
h3 {
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="Nav">
            <div id="Nav_Button"><p>Button</p></div>
            <div id="Nav_Title"><h3>Super Snack Stadium</h3></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood you correctly, you're already on the right track, but you did not specify that it should be centered.

```
#Nav_Button {

  display: flex;

  border: 1px solid black;
  /*Flex Child Code*/
  order: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;

  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

See here you use a div and this div has default display: block;
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp

And here for align-items and justify-content
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container

Answer (score 0):

````
.parent_container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

/*Containers within ".parent container"*/

.Nav {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    /*Flex Child Code*/
    order:1;
    /*Flex Parent Code*/
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    position: relative;

}

/*--------Children of .Nav ---------*/

#Nav_Button {
    border: 1px solid black;
    /*Flex Child Code*/
    width: 300px;
}

#Nav_Title {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    /*Flex Child Code*/
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
#Nav_Title h3 {
    margin: 14px;
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}


/*Containers within ".parent container"*/

.Nav {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  /*Flex Child Code*/
  order: 1;
  /*Flex Parent Code*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
}

h3 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: -5px;
}

/*--------Children of .Nav ---------*/

#Nav_Button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  /*Flex Child Code*/
  order: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#Nav_Title {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  /*Flex Child Code*/
  order: 2;
  flex-grow: 8;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent container">
  <!--Navigational Bar-->
  <div class="Nav">
    <div id="Nav_Button">
      <p>Button</p>
    </div>
    <div id="Nav_Title">
      <h3>Super Snack Stadium</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```